# Simple Question Why Does Pressing P not start the BGE?

Tags: game-engine, shortcut

Pressing P in Game Logic Mode Does Not Work Anymore I Checked and the shortcut is the same still. if I press Space to bring up the search and type in game
it says "Wm: start game in player" upon clicking that it works but
pressing "P" does not do this anymore and it gets kinda frustrating searching it up every time I wanna test the game logic, so How do I get the shortcut to work again. oh, a little more bit of detail changing the shortcut also does not fix my problem ether.

Comment: Up the top switch blender from "Blender Render" to "Blender Game"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until Blender 2.49, P key put you right into the game engine.

Blender 2.5 introduced a special concept called Render Engine (Internal, Game, Cycles), and you must choose the right engine to configure it. When you choose the game engine render engine, the properties editor and some other ui menus and panels will update. Pressing P will also now put you in the game engine mode.